# ENUM without a method to get value

Tags: java, enums

I have this enum:

```
public enum MyEnum{

    A("a"),
    B("b"),

    private String value;
    MyEnum(String value){ this.value = value; }

    public String getValue(){ return value; }

}
```

And I call this like: `MyEnum.A.getValue();` which return `a`

I can do something to call like: `MyEnum.A`, without `getValue()` and get `a`?

Comment: No. `MyEnum.A` is an expression that resolves to a reference to the enum constant.

Comment: It's a private field, so you need a public method,no?

Comment: @user7294900 that's not a problem. I can change the scope.

Comment: @KunLun Do you always want the lowercase name of the enum variable?

Comment: Do you want to print a value? you can override toString and print value

Comment: @Avi no, that is just an example.

Comment: There's probably no way to do it, then.

Comment: @user7294900 I doesn't help me to change `MyEnum.A.getValue()` with `MyEnum.A.value`. My intention is to make it shorter.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There is no way to change that? Like `List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(); a.add(1); a.add(2); System.out.println(a);` print `[1, 2]` and not reference.

Comment: That's because `println` invokes `toString` on `a`. If that's what you want, override `toString` in the enum to return the value of `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At best, you can override toString() to make things understandable and short:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    A("a"),
    B("b"),

    private String value;
    MyEnum(String value){ this.value = value; }
    public String toString() { return this.value; }
}
```

Comment: You can still keep `getValue()` if you'd like, but it's redundant unless you're using it for purposes other than printing.

Comment: Is it okay to do this for comparission? For example if(MyEnum.A.equals("a"))

Answer (score 1):

You can only print a value if you override `toString`'s Object method

```
 System.out.println(MyEnum.A);
```

Comment: This is literally my answer, just less complete and later.